# Ext JS 7.3.1 Classic Bug - Invalid state for C on record save

Tags: session, extjs, save, viewmodel

Here is a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3alr).

To reproduce the problem:

1. Create form panel with Session;
2. Create new record through viewModel links config;
3. Call save on the record without any modifications;

I think the bug is in the viewModel's linkTo method:

```
    if (Ext.isObject(create)) {
        rec.set(create);
        rec.commit();
        rec.phantom = true;
    }
```

Maybe the record must be committed silent?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a record without the id field set it should be phantom true.  And dirty is set to false.   It is assuming that the values that you initially set are what is in the database or where ever the record is located.  If you check if the record is dirty and only run save when you have changed the name field (dirty = true) it saves ok.  When you set the id field the record is no longer phantom.

You should be able to call save with dirty set to false and have the system just do nothing.  On a store if you call sync that is what happens.... it skips the non-dirty records and only operates on the dirty records.

When phantom is true save will call the proxy "create" method.  When phantom is false save will call the proxy's "update" method.  If you drop (record.drop())  the record is marked as dropped and save will call the proxy's "destroy" method.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3an0)

Comment: You are right. But the problem here is in that after record.commit(), crudState is R (not C) and then after record.save() it throws error "Invalid state for C on record save". You can see it in the Console.

Comment: I added a commit to the fiddle.  It seems that as long as you only save when dirty you can save and commit with no error.